# Android ListView with custom adapter crashing on SM-T280 tablet

Tags: android, listview, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have two Samsung tablets (Samsung SM-T580 Android 7.0 and SM-T280 Android 5.1).
I have a list view with a custom adapter. It works fine on the SM-T580 but it crashes on the first iteration of method:

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

on the SM-T280 tablet. I do not understand how it works perfect on the SM-T580 and crashes on the SM-T280. The error message when it crashes is:

> The application is in break mode.
>
> Your app has entered a break state, but there is no code to show because all threads were executing external code (typically system or framework code.)

I have the compiler set to:

```
Compile using Android version: (Target Framework)
Android 5.1 (Lollipop)
```

I am using Visual Studio 2017 with Xamarin.

The following is my code.

The layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TableLayout
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stretchColumns="2"
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1">
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/CompanyNameLabel"
                android:text=""
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:padding="8dip" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/CompanySalesLabel"
                android:text=""
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:padding="8dip" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/CompanyAddressLabel"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="20dip" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/CompanyCityStateZipLabel"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="20dip" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The view holder code:

```
public class MyMainCompanyRowHolder : Java.Lang.Object
{
    public TextView CompanyName { get; set; }
    public TextView CompanyAddress { get; set; }
    public TextView CompanySales { get; set; }
    public TextView CompanyCityStateZipLabel { get; set; }
    public static T Cast<T>(Java.Lang.Object obj) where T : MyMainCompanyRowHolder
    {
        var propInfo = obj.GetType().GetProperty("Instance");
        return propInfo == null ? null : propInfo.GetValue(obj, null) as T;
    }
}
```

The custom adapter:

```
public class ListAdapter : BaseAdapter<Company>
{
    List<Company> company;
    Activity context;

    public ListAdapter(Activity currentContext, List<Company> companyList) : base()
    {
        this.company = companyList;
        this.context = currentContext;

    }

    public override Company this[int position]
    {
        get { return company.ToArray()[position]; }
    }

    public override int Count
    {
        get { return company.Count; }
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        Models.ViewHolder.MyMainCompanyRowHolder myViewHolder = null;

        View view = convertView;

        if (view != null)
            myViewHolder = Models.ViewHolder.MyMainCompanyRowHolder.Cast<Models.ViewHolder.MyMainCompanyRowHolder>(view.Tag);

        if (myViewHolder == null)
        {
            myViewHolder = new Models.ViewHolder.MyMainCompanyRowHolder();
            //view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, null);
            view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.MainCompanyListRow, null);

            myViewHolder.CompanyName = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.CompanyNameLabel);
            myViewHolder.CompanyAddress = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.CompanyAddressLabel);
            myViewHolder.CompanySales = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.CompanySalesLabel);
            myViewHolder.CompanyCityStateZipLabel = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.CompanyCityStateZipLabel);

            view.Tag = myViewHolder;

        }
        myViewHolder.CompanyName.Text = company.ToArray()[position].CompanyName;
        myViewHolder.CompanyAddress.Text = company.ToArray()[position].Address;
        myViewHolder.CompanySales.Text = company.ToArray()[position].ActualSales.ToString("C0");
        myViewHolder.CompanyCityStateZipLabel.Text = company.ToArray()[position].City + ", " + company.ToArray()[position].State + " " + company.ToArray()[position].Zip;  
        return view;
    }
}
```

The call in the Activity module:

```
myCompany = myDBF.getCompany("");
var listView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.OrderMethodListView);
listView.Adapter = new Models.Adapters.ListAdapter(this, myCompany);
```

Comment: What line in your code does it fail on? And what is reported in `logcat`?

Comment: It crashes right after the "return view;" in the GetView method in ListAdapter. It crashes after the first iteration. I have 25 companies in the array. The GetView method should executed 25 times when the adapter is set. I have not checked the log cat yet. The code works fine on the SM-T580.

Comment: Allow the exception to occur, continue the app (do not abort it) and get the crash details.

Comment: A logcat data would definitely help.

Comment: I will check the logcat tomorrow morning. Although I'm fairly new to Android development, this error seems bizarre.

Comment: The following is from the debug log:An unhandled exception occured.

12-05 16:12:17.936 E/AndroidRuntime(16249):  at android.view.View.layout(View.j12-05 16:12:17.936 E/AndroidRuntime(16249): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-05 16:12:17.936 E/AndroidRuntime(16249): Process: CRM.CRM, PID: 16249
12-05 16:12:17.936 E/AndroidRuntime(16249): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.View.getVisibility()' on a null object reference
12-05 16:12:17.936 E/AndroidRuntime(16249):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.forceUniformHeight(LinearLayout.java:1379)

Comment: Hi, remove the `android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" ` which id is `CompanyNameLabel` and id is `CompanySalesLabel` (TableRow's children)

Comment: Thanks! I figured it out. Android 5.1 does not like: android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_column="1"
android:layout_gravity="left"  Once I removed those lines from my Layout Code it works.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! I figured it out. Android 5.1 does not like:

```
android:layout_weight="1" 
android:layout_column="1" 
android:layout_gravity="left"
```

Once I removed those lines from my Layout Code, the app works correctly.